# Handling Soft Keyboard Events Android

Tags: android, service, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm currently on the preliminary phase of a project that a potential client request me, he wants a mobile app on Android for educational purposes, he wants to catch all words typed with the OS soft keyboard on all applications, i'm not sure if this is possible and i have been searching about any documentation of it.

Searching on the Android official developers docs, I found this note: "Note: When handling keyboard events with the Key-event class and related APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only from a hardware keyboard. You should never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard)."

After reading that note, i'm not sure if that app is possible, and less sure , what can i say to my client.

If anyone knows something about that implementation, please let me know!!

Comment: Yes ronsuez this not possible. This is very unsecured. If user enter his Login credentials and you suppose to be catch it it is very unsecured

Comment: well, i read about it and you right, but what if i implement a custom input method (IME) for such task?

Comment: Yes you have to develop custom keyboard using google IME:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_IME